# React-Navigation: Hide Parent header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Problem:** i have a DrawerNavigator that contains a TabNavigator which contains a StackNavigator, what i needed is the regular three bar icon in the header to open the Drawer instead of swiping right

**My Solution:** put the TabNavigator that contains a StackNavigator inside a StackNavigator and put the StackNavigator inside the DrawerNavigator

**Problem with my solution:** when i navigate inside the TabNavigator i get double headers (it's normal because i have 2 StackNavigators) and i can only hide the back arrow header, i always get left with the 3 tabs icon header.

so how please how can i hide the parent header which contains TabNavigator?

```js
//the drawer navigator
const DNav = DrawerNavigator({
        SportWall: {
            screen: SportWall
            }
        })
        
//the stack that contains the tab navigator
export default StackNavigator({
    SportWall: {
        //just to show the header with the 3 bars icon
        screen: SportWall
    }
    
render() {
  return (
      <Tabs/>
  )
}
    
//the tab navigator
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    AllPubs: {
        screen: AllPubs
    },
    FriendsPubs: {
        screen: FriendsPubs
    },
});

//the stack inside each tab 
export default StackNavigator({
    AllPubs: {
        screen: AllPubs,
    },
    Pub: {
        screen: Pub, navigationOptions: {tabBarVisible: false}
    },...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use your `StackNavigator` like this example and use the `headerMode: 'screen'`:

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
  },{ 
    headerMode: 'screen' 
  }
);
```

See [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/803) for more information.

Comment: changing the headerMode of the HomeScreen to 'screen' wouldn't hide it when navigating inside the tabs because the HomeScreen has it's own stacknavigator and each tab has it's own stacknavigator

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use a StackNavigator just to show the header that shows the drawer.
You could set a custom header with the hamburger button at left that fires the drawer onPress for all the screens that need it:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
  title="Open drawer"
/>
```

don't forget to add `headerMode: "none"` to the Navigator options